# Grape entities with has_many through relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api, grape-entity

I'm adding REST api with the grape gem. I also added the grape-entities gem. What I need is that data from these three models: Product, Company and ManufactureCompany in one json file.

The relationships in `product.rb`:

```
has_many :manufacture_companies
has_many :manufacturers, :through => :manufacture_companies, :source => :company
```

The `products.rb` file:

```
class Products < Grape::API
  resource :products do
    get do
        @products = Product.all
        present @products, with: Entities::Product
    end
  end
end
```

And `entities.rb`:

```
class Product < Grape::Entity
  expose :id, :name,:description, :barcode
  expose :net_weight, :reference_unit
  expose :prepare_instructions, :storage_instructions, :origin
  expose :manufacturers, using: Entities::Company
end

class Company < Grape::Entity
  expose :id
  expose :name
end
```

The entities are probably wrong. I saw that with a has_many relationship you can just say `expose :something, using: Entities::RelatedModel` but in this case, the related model has only product_id and company_id (and own id). Couldn't find any example on the net.

Comment: So what happens when you try the code you've got?

Comment: @SimonSouth 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, or some other indication of which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: The problem is that the manufacturers have two foreign keys. It needs to know the proudct_id and company_id. So even if I said :manufacturers (this can be any name (not even the attrib in the model)) there's no connection to the middle table. No idea how to write it. I tried every combination. (using: Entities::ManufactureCompany ... )

Comment: What is the error message you're seeing? Your code not only looks correct to me but so far (from the Rails console) is working correctly for me as well.

Comment: The error message in the one from the first answer (Internal Server Error). Hm, interesting. Doesn't work for me. BTW, you need to access the json data with `localhost:3000/api/v1/products.json`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find exaclty what I want, but I found an alternative. I had to give up from Entities. I defined the Products class like this:

```
module API
# Projects API
  class Products < Grape::API
    resource :products do
      get do
        @products = Product.all.as_json(include: 
          [{distributors: {only: [:id, :name, :address, :phone, :fax, :email, :website, :pib]}}, 
          {manufacturers: {only: [:id, :name, :address, :phone, :fax, :email, :website, :pib]}},
       :photos,
          {ingredients: {only: [:name, :alternative_name, :description]}},
          #...
       ], 
        only: [:id, :name, :barcode, :description, :prepare_instructions, :storage_instructions, :net_weight, :reference_unit, :origin]
        )
     end
    end
  end
end
```